# Adobe Animate Snap SVG plugin - huge files

Tags: flash, animation, svg, adobe, snap.svg

I'm trying to use the Snap.SVG plugin for Adobe Animate CC for the first time and I'm getting a huge JSON file as output.

My file is simple, I have a square in the middle of the canvas and it's rotating from 0 degrees to 360 degrees. There are 145 frames but only 2 keyframes, one for the start and one for the end.

The problem seems to be that the exporter is producing one snap svg command for every frame of the animation, not every keyframe, so I have an 18Kb file with over 1000 lines of code (once formatted using jsonlint), just to rotate a simple rectangle through 360 degrees.

I'm assuming that can't be right and that I need to change how I'm setting up my stage in Adobe Animate CC, or I'm doing something else wrong.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the creator of the plugin who confirmed that this was currently the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

There are better plugins for exporting SVG from Adobe Animate CC. The best is "Flash2svg". and it is VERY efficient in reducing the exported file size. It is also capable of embedding all animations in the SVG file (audio included!). I always use it instead of the bloated native exporter.

You can download the free plugin from here:
https://github.com/TomByrne/Flash2Svg

Or install it from Adobe Plugins panel:
https://creative.adobe.com/addons/products/7232

Comment: This does not seek to answer the question at all

Comment: I assume that "embedding all animations in the SVG file" means that it's using SMIL? If so then this is no good because it is not supported in browsers (and those that do won't soon).